# Why are variables of type size_t casted to (unsigned) in a printf call?

Tags: c, unsigned, strlen

I was writing a program and looking up strlen() function on this website http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/. I saw that in the example where the function was used, the author of the code put (unsigned) to cast the result of the function to unsigned. I understand that it is done so because the function returns size_t type, which is unsigned, but is this really necessary?

```
/* strlen example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szInput[256];
  printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
  gets (szInput);
  printf ("The sentence entered is %u characters long.\n",(unsigned)strlen(szInput));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the code example this is because it is the argument corresponding to a `%u` format specifier in `printf`.

The variadic arguments for `printf` must have exactly the correct type for the specifier, otherwise [the behaviour is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/).  The argument type for `%u` is `unsigned`.

`size_t` is a typedef that may or may not resolve to `unsigned`, so the cast is necessary for the call to be well-defined on all platforms.

Another approach would be to use the `%zu` format specifier which is designed for `size_t`, although that has a practical issue that it will fail if the library is not C99-compliant.

Comment: 3rd approach, especially good for C89: `printf ("%lu\n",(unsigned long)strlen(szInput));` - Good for the general case unlike the small `char szInput[256];` here.

Comment: This was a particular issue with Microsoft compilers that did not add even partial support for C99 until VC++2013 and it was not until VC++2015 that a majority of C99 was supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is done for portability.  There is a modifier for `size_t` format descriptors, using the letter `z`, as in `%zu` (meaning unsigned format for `size_t` operand) that will make to accept a `size_t` argument, independent of the architecture you are using.

Depending on the flavour of unix you use, of the standard you follow, you'll encounter systems in which `z` is accepted or not, in which `size_t` exists or not (very old systems had no `size_t` type) so, as the result of `strlen()` is probably known to the author of the code to be short, then the most portable solution is to convert the data to a type that is allowed by `printf()` and then use a known format specifier.  In your case the author decided to use `(unsigned)` as probably the program has changed from 32bit architectures (with or without the `z` modifier) to 64bit one, without the knowledge of if it needs an `unsigned int` or an `unsigned long` to specify the result.  As the string is short enough to fit in an `unsigned`, there's no need to use the `z` modifier, which probably is either not known to the user, or not present in the compiler implementation used by her/him.

This is quite common as one letter should be reserved in systems for `off_t`, `dev_t`, `ino_t`, etc. Many of them operating system dependant, and not included in the standard the user is normally programming.